# How to remove response headers location when doing http request via postman and logic app HTTP connector

Tags: postman, httprequest, azure-logic-apps

Is there any way to remove the response header location when making a post via HTTP connector in the logic app or via a postman?

Response Headers
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Location: http://xxxx.xxx/api/integrationstatus?id=xxxxx
Date: Thu, 11 Mar 2021 10:13:53 GMT

Comment: Hi Dinesh, may I know if the answer I provided below helps your question ? If it works, could you please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) it as answer(click on the check mark beside my answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thanks in advance~

Answer (score 0):

If you mean remove the `Location` field from response header just inside the HTTP connector, I'm afraid the answer is "no". And to remove it inside postman, the answer is also "no".

But if your requirement is to get the data of response header, at that time remove the `location` field. This can be implemented, here provide two solutions for your reference.

**1.** We can do it by "[Execute Javascript Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-add-run-inline-code#add-inline-code)" action in your logic app. Before use "Execute Javascript Code" action, you need to [create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-create-integration-account?tabs=azure-portal#create-integration-account) integration account and [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-create-integration-account?tabs=azure-portal#link-to-logic-app) it to your logic app. Then use the js code like below screenshot:

[image]

**2.** If you do not want to create integration account to use "Execute Javascript Code" action. You can also do it by "[Compose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#compose-action)" action. List all of other fields in "Compose" by their expression. For example, the expression for `Cache-Control` is `outputs('HTTP')['headers']?['Cache-Control']`.

[image]